# Setting JSON Ajax string into variables with Jquery then append an <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an Ajax script that is currently receiving a JSON data string and appending the data to a `<li>` on the page, like this:

[image]

This is the Jquery script I am using to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form.quform').Quform({
  successStart: function (response) {
  var li = $("<li>").text(JSON.stringify(response));
  $("#response").append(li)
```

But I want to assign variables to the 5 field results and display them in spans so they look something like after I add css to them:

[image]

I have tried different things to get this to work, and read a lot of stack articles, One [Stack article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334341/jquery-javascript-json-to-string-variable-dump/3334351#3334351) says to assign the string a variable like this `var data = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);`, but it has not worked. This is the last thing I have tried, but I know it is not right. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form.quform').Quform({
    successStart: function (response) {
      var data = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
      var content = "balance: " + data.balance + " account_number:" + data.account_number;
      var li = $("<li><span>").text(content);
      $("#response").parent().append(li);
```

Also this is the JSON string I receive to the page:

```
{"type":"success","message":"Your message has been sent, thank you.","record":{"id":108,"bank_name":"Jane Doe","balance":"200","account_number":"8765432187654321","customer_id":"250","monthly":"50"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `var data = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);` there doesn't make sense because `myObject` and `replacer` are not defined. Don't just copy and paste code. The other answers just provided the general signature of `JSON.stringify`. You already know how to use it, because you used it in your first code snippet.

---

Anyways, `JSON.stringify` converts an existing object/array to a string containing JSON, which also means that `response` **already is an object**. So all you have to do is access its properties. In your case,

```
var data = response.record;
```

will set `data` to the correct value.

More info: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: Thanks for your help.... that makes sense, then how do I separate the fields names from the values when setting the variable. I don't want to show it like this `bank_name":"Jane Doe`, I would only want to show `jane doe`

Comment: You don't have to. If `var x = {foo: "bar"};` is an object, then `x.foo` returns `"bar"`. Hence `data.bank_name` returns `"Jane Doe"`. This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explains quite well how objects work.

Comment: I still am not getting it, am I suppose to change this also `var li = $("<li>").text(JSON.stringify(response));` or just add this `var data = response.record;` on the next line. Sorry, I just have no experience with JSON.

Comment: In your second code snippet, replace `var data = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);` with `var data = response.record;`. You should also change `var li = $("<li><span>").text(content);` to `var li = $("<li>").text(content);`. `$("<li><span>")` won't work.

Comment: oh don't use JSON you are saying

Comment: Yes in the way you think about it, no in the general case. JSON is a language-indpendent, textual data exchange format (like XML, CSV or YAML). The server sends JSON as response to the client and then it can be *parsed* into JavaScript objects/arrays. In this case jQuery does the the parsing for you, hence `response` is already a JavaScript object and not a string containing JSON. `JSON.stringify` coverts objects/arrays *to* JSON.

Comment: well yesterday someone suggested I use JSON after I posted a similar question and that is why I tried it. This is the thread I am talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209668/displaying-data-from-an-ajax-response-with-jquery

Comment: FWIWI, JSON doesn't have to do anything with jQuery and whether you use JSON or not doesn't matter anymore at this point. All that's important is that `response` is an object. Looks like you were already on the right track with your code in the other question.

Comment: I have been playing with it using this ` jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('form.quform').Quform({
     successStart: function (response) {
      var data = response.record;
    var content = "balance: " + data.record.balance + " account_number:" + data.record.account_number;
    var li = $("<li>").text(content);
    $(".myData").parent().append(li);`

Comment: But it does not work, the form still submits data, but it does not do anything. the loading animation continues spinning, so its like the script is missing something

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your response is a JSON response, you would not need to do:

```
var data= JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```

Besides, myObject and replacer seem to be undefined. Also, it looks like this line:

```
var content = "balance: " + data.balance + " account_number:" + data.account_number;
```

should be:

```
var content = "balance: " + data.record.balance + " account_number:" + data.record.account_number;
```

If this does not work then try the following:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(response);
var content = "balance: " + data.balance + " account_number:" + data.account_number;
```

This will actually parse the response variable to an object that you can then access through "data.record".

Comment: I thought parse was the opposite. If I wanted to send the string back to the server, I would use that to format an object

Comment: See [parseJSON Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/). It takes a JSON string and returns a POJO (Plain Old Javascript Object).

Comment: I had one more question... based on your answer, I could just keep it the way it is, then set a variable for the string. What would that look like `var data = $.text(JSON.stringify(response));`

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. I suggest you take a look at @Felix Kling's comment.